# How can I map images in React from firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, firebase-storage, use-effect

Here I am trying to get productList from MySQL database and for each product object I am assigning new property - imageURL via getImages(). When I log productList to console, there is property imageURL with correct url. Problem is, when I try to map it, it shows nothing. Why?

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("/assets")

const [productList, setProductList] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/product/get").then((response) => {
        setProductList(response.data)
    })  
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    getImages(productList)
}, [productList])


const getImages = (array) => {
    array.forEach((item) => {
        storageRef.child(`${item.bannerImage}`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
            item.imageURL = url
        })
    })
}
```

My map function:

```
{productList.map((val) => {
    return (
        <div key={val.id} className="product">
            <div className="item">
                <h1>Product title: {val.title}</h1>
                <h2>Price: {val.price}</h2>
                <h2>Quantity: {val.quantity}</h2>
                <h2>IMAGE: {val.imageURL}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) 
})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems:**

> 1. You are not setting `productList` back in `getImages` function. You are just iterating over array.
> 2. `getDownloadURL` is a `async` function, you should not use it inside loop. The best way to do this is through a `recursive` function. But you can also do this as below:

### Solution

**Your `getImage` function**

```
const getImage = async (bannerImage) => {
     const url = await storageRef.child(bannerImage).getDownloadURL();
     return url;   
}
```

**then your `map` function**

```
{productList.map((val) => {
    return (
        <div key={val.id} className="product">
            <div className="item">
                <h1>Product title: {val.title}</h1>
                <h2>Price: {val.price}</h2>
                <h2>Quantity: {val.quantity}</h2>
                <h2>IMAGE: {getImage(val.bannerImage)}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) 
})}
```

Comment: Thanks! But now it throws an error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. This error points to setProductList() in useEffect().

Comment: Okay, can you please tell me what is val.bannerImage by doing console.log? Is it a string or something else!

Comment: It is a [object Promise]

Comment: Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: "<URL to image>"

Comment: And can you please check the `url` inside getImage as well in the console?

Comment: In getImage it returns the actual URL

Comment: So I googled a bit and I found that async function return promise which result value can be accessed by using .then() after this async function. That is why it can't render properly. How can I render an actual value from this promise inside .map?

Comment: It should not return promise because we used await. Did you use that or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create another small component for your image rendering and handle async for `getDownloadURL` behaviour inside that component

```
function ProductImage({bannerImage}) {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('')
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getImage(bannerImage) {
      const url = await bannerImage.getDownloadURL()
      setImageUrl(url)
    }
    getImage(bannerImage)
  }, [bannerImage])

  return imageUrl ? <h2>IMAGE: {imageUrl}</h2> : '...Loading'
 }
```

And use this component in your main component

```
{productList.map((val) => {
    return (
        <div key={val.id} className="product">
            <div className="item">
                <h1>Product title: {val.title}</h1>
                <h2>Price: {val.price}</h2>
                <h2>Quantity: {val.quantity}</h2>
                <ProductImage bannerImage={val.bannerImage} />
            </div>
        </div>
    ) 
})}
```

Comment: Gonna try this!